# Nuget Package dll generated with ILMerge (problems with XML documentation)

Tags: xml, nuget-package, ilmerge

I'm generating a Nuget Package dll generated from ILMerge.

1º - The code was inserted in Post-build event command line:
"$(ProjectDir)....\packages\ilmerge.2.13.0307\ILMerge.exe" "$(ProjectDir)....\05-ILMergeDlls\Custom.Framework.ExtensionInt.dll" "$(ProjectDir)....\05-ILMergeDlls\Custom.Framework.ExtensionString.dll" /ndebug /log /out:"$(ProjectDir)....\05-ILMergeDlls\Custom.Framework.dll". Image1: https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-D28vgwy8eb0/UrLRrfLcC0I/AAAAAAAABIg/-4BKu_MZjyU/w665-h485-no/01-Package.jpg

2º - My nuspec file and when installing the package, appears in the directory two XML documentation files: Image2: https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-ttIt9aWGR4U/UrLb_ZGX9HI/AAAAAAAABJg/0i9POZHgwx4/w1090-h694-no/02-NuspecFile-FilesXML.jpg

Any idea why they appear?
Actually I would like to include the XML documentation file of the merged dll, even tried this using the command / xmldocs in ILMerge, but the same thing happened, can someone help me?

PS: Windows 8, Visual Studio 2010 SP1, C#, ILMerge 2.13.0307

In advance, thank you!
Still can not post pictures directly, so only insert links.

Answer (score 0):

Although /xmldocs is supposed to work (did you check the merged XML wasn't generated in the current folder instead ?), you can try using [ILRepack](https://github.com/gluck/il-repack) instead.

Comment: If I use the command "/ xmldocs" the generated XML is correct, but the problem occurs after generating the nuspec package dll and XML, the package is displayed correctly, but after installation, appears 2 XML files and not 1 .. . I'll check the possibilities with ILRepack ... thank you!